# NSArray - getting the closest object to origin

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray, sorting

using Objective-C for iPhone, I'm attempting to gather the closest object to my origin.
All my objects are in an NSMutableArray and have CGPoint property of their current location.

Using simple trig I can find the magnitudes of all my objects with ease, but *Im trying to find the **'closest'** object to my origin*. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Are we talking GPS locations or planar coordinates, simple coordinates across a plane can be calculated with the distance formula while GPS locations require taking the curvature of the earth into consideration.

Comment: When you say magnitude do you mean distance? Seems like you pretty much have all the information you need already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loop through all the objects, calculate the distance to your origin while keeping the minimum value?

```
distanceAO = sqrt(sqr(Ax-Ox)+sqr(Ay-Oy))
```

Comment: Yeah i think this is the way to go. I already have the distance property for all my objects that im iterating through. I simply need to find the smallest value of these. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
CGFloat minDistance = FLT_MAX;
MyClass *minObject = nil;
for (MyClass *obj in objects)
{
    if ([obj distanceFromOrigin] < minDistance)
    {
        minObject = obj;
        minDistance = [obj distanceFromOrigin];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are sorting methods for NSArray which easies your work.
[have a look at this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003620)

i am not sure exactly which method solves your case but have a look into those methods you can definitely achieve it

TNQ